# observeValue called twice on UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, key-value-observing

My main view controller is added as observer for some key in `UserDefault`. But every time the value changed, `observeValue` is called twice.

The stacks are different for these two calls.

The first one is from

`frame #6: forEachObserver + 332
frame #7: -[CFPrefsSource didChangeValues:forKeys:count:] + 68
frame #8: -[CFPrefsSource setValues:forKeys:count:removeValuesForKeys:count:] + 340
frame #9: -[CFPrefsSource setValue:forKey:] + 56`

The second one is from

`frame #6: forEachObserver + 332
frame #7: -[CFPrefsSource _notifyObserversOfChangeFromValuesForKeys:toValuesForKeys:] + 68
frame #8: __84-[CFPrefsSearchListSource asynchronouslyNotifyOfChangesFromDictionary:toDictionary:]_block_invoke_2 + 36`

The only related post I found is from cocoa-dev mail list https://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2016/Nov/msg00084.html. It seems this issue appears from MacOS 10.12

Can someone provide more details on why it happens or how to suppress the duplicate messages?

A minimal example to reproduce:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(
            self,
            forKeyPath: "test",
            options: .new,
            context: nil
        )

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "test")
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("Observed: \(object ?? "None")")
    }
}
```

Comment: iOS or macOS or both? How do you register the observer? A [mcve] would help others to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Both. I can reproduce it in iOS 10.3.2 and macOS 10.12.5. But it works correctly in playground

Comment: I do not know the answer, but I can confirm your observation. It seems that `UserDefaults.standard.set()` always causes a callback call, followed by another callback call if the value actually changed.

Comment: It is a bug, and fixed in iOS 11/macOS 10.13, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464568/1187415.