# MacOS uses KVO to perform multiple executions

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("in viewDidLoad");
        // addObserver keyPath
        UserDefaults.standard.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "testKey", options: .new, context: nil);

        print("out viewDidLoad");
    }

    deinit {
        // removeObserver keyPath
        UserDefaults.standard.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "testKey");
    }

    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        print("in observeValue keyPath: \(keyPath) value: \(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "testKey"))");
        // 1. If I execute the func click () method, it will be executed two times
        // 2. If App originally existed "testKey", then func observeValue () will be executed after the viewDidLoad is finished.
    }

    @IBAction func click(_ sender: NSButton) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(arc4random(), forKey: "testKey");
    }
}
```

The above code is all of my test code. I used KVO in my own project, but found repeated execution.

**// 1. If I execute the func click () method, it will be executed two times**

**// 2. If App originally existed "testKey", then func observeValue () will be executed after the viewDidLoad is finished.**

This is not what I understand about KVO. My idea is that after addObserver, my observeValue will be called if my key is changed. But it didn't turn out that way. I tried to find the answer to the forum, and I didn't find the answer. I just found a similar question.

If I press Button in my view, then the final result will be..:

```
in viewDidLoad
out viewDidLoad
in observeValue keyPath: Optional("testKey") value: 4112410111
in observeValue keyPath: Optional("testKey") value: 3712484288
in observeValue keyPath: Optional("testKey") value: 3712484288
```

macos： 10.12.6 (16G29)
xcode: 9 beta6、xcode 8.3.3

If you have the same problem, please tell more people to help us solve it. Thank you

**I have sent the same question to the official, and if there is a solution, I will return it here.**

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266733/observevalue-called-twice-on-userdefaults, unfortunately without a solution.

Comment: Looking forward to solving the problem, this is not in line with expectations.

Comment: It is a bug, and fixed in iOS 11/macOS 10.13, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45464568/1187415.

Answer (score 0):

From setting a breakpoint in `observeValue()` and looking at the trace, it appears that the observations are getting fired in two places; one during `click()` as an effect of the line where you tell `UserDefaults` to set the value, and another later on, scheduled on the run loop so it happens after `click()` has already returned, when the system detects that the value has changed. This double notification could probably be considered a bug, since the latter notification should render the former unnecessary, and I'd consider filing a [radar report](http://bugreport.apple.com) on it.

Unfortunately, I can't see any way to disable this behavior. I *can* think of a workaround, but it's extremely hacky, kludgey, ugly, and I probably wouldn't actually do it unless the need is absolutely dire. But here it is:

```
private var kvoContext = 0

private let ignoreKVOKey = "com.charlessoft.example.IgnoreKVO"

// If this can be called from a thread other than the main thread,
// then you will need to take measures to protect it against race conditions
private var shouldIgnoreKVO = false

override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if context == &self.kvoContext { // always, always use a context pointer
        if !shouldIgnoreKVO { // if this is a notification we don't want, ignore it
            print("in observeValue keyPath: \(String(describing: keyPath)) value: \(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "testKey"))");
        }
    } else {
        // call super if context pointer doesn't match ours
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
    }
}

@IBAction func click(_ sender: NSButton) {
    // we don't need this notification, since we'll get the later one
    // resulting from the defaults having changed
    self.shouldIgnoreKVO = true
    defer { self.shouldIgnoreKVO = false }

    UserDefaults.standard.set(arc4random(), forKey: "testKey");
}
```

Again, it's ugly, it's hacky, I probably wouldn't actually do it. But there it is.